# Angular 2 i18n Extraction failed error

Tags: angular, internationalization, translation

I have the following problem using the ng-xi18n command:

```
c:\Users\Documents\bptt_webclient>node_modules\.bin\ng-xi18n                                                                                                                    
Error: parameters received {"filePath":"c:/Users/Documents/bptt_webclient/node_modules/@angular/common/src/location/location.d.ts","name":"Location"} which is not a StaticSymbo
l                                                                                                                                                                                              
    at StaticReflector.parameters (c:\Users\Documents\bptt_webclient\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.js:92:19)                                          
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (c:\Users\Documents\bptt_webclient\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14317:56)                      
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (c:\Users\Documents\bptt_webclient\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14282:28)                              
    at c:\Users\Documents\bptt_webclient\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14425:43                                                                        
    at Array.forEach (native)                                                                                                                                                                  
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProvidersMetadata (c:\Users\Documents\bptt_webclient\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14405:21)                         
    at c:\Users\Documents\bptt_webclient\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14412:43                                                                        
    at Array.forEach (native)                                                                                                                                                                  
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProvidersMetadata (c:\Users\Documents\bptt_webclient\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14405:21)                         
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (c:\Users\Documents\bptt_webclient\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14164:60)                          
Extraction failed
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Node Version: v6.6.0

Angular: 2.0.0

Thanks for your time and help :)

EDIT: What worked for me is to uncomment the lines, that threw the error in the static.reflector.js. There is still an error, but also a new .xlf file. Just a temporary solution.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all imports of `RouterTestingModule` and wait for the following issue to be fixed.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11276

Comment: After removing the ```RouterTestingModule```, I ran into another error coming from primeng/datatables, maybe because it is not AOT ready yet.    

AOT seems to be very unstable...

Comment: Yes, primeng is not AOT compatible yet: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/pull/1004 I removed all primeng components temporarily...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n -p src/tsconfig.json` as it mentioned on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2201)... It generates `.xlf` for me without any error.

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I am running into the same issue now

Comment: I'm facing the same issue too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try creating a script in your **package.json**??

***package.json***

```
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

And run the script from the **command line**

```
$ npm run i18n
```